# Highcharts Pie Chart - slice color dependent of category

Tags: highcharts, colors, slice

I would like to make the color of the slices dependend of the category['A','B','C','D']. Example, if the category 'B' is in the dataset, it should always be orange. My example doesn't work because I use the keys attribute in combination with data and it should be category. I don't seem to find a way doing this if at all possible?

```
{
series: [{
keys: ['y', 'color'],
data: [
  ['A', 'red'],
  ['B', 'orange'],
  ['C', '#abcf44'],
  ['D', '#acb222']
]
}]
```

}

Dataset:

Category          %
A               10%
B               30%
C               10%
D               30%

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IMjz.png)
[Example pie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSXHf.png)

Comment: Hi @Robelem, Could you describe the problem more precisely? How does your dataset look like? What will define `y` value?

Comment: Hi ppotaczek, I added an example of the dataset. I hope this helps to understand. Because the dataset will be dynamic and will sometimes contain only A and B or B,C,D etc.. and therefor the slice color must be depended of category and not the data

Answer (score 0):

You can define your data as an array of objects with defined `name`, `color` and `y` properties:

```
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    data: [{
      name: 'A',
      color: 'red',
      y: 10
    }, {
      name: 'C',
      color: 'orange',
      y: 30
    }, {
      name: 'D',
      color: '#abcf44',
      y: 10
    }]
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jenfgwdk/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.data